# How to handle multiple conditions for a a new column - DAX Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there a way of placing three different types of variables into a one column using switch? Or is there a better way of doing it? Or can it be done?

So I have one set of parameters that work in the switch but a few tricky ones that dont work. Here is what I have so far.

Var a = switch ([customer],
"Customer 1001" , "USA",
"Customer 1002", "Asia", "Other  ...... and so on

Var b = if [Customer] = "Customer 2002" && [cat] <> "Household" THEN " USA" else "Europe"
Var c = if [Customer] = "Customer 2002" && [order date] > "2021/10/01" then "USA" else "Asia"

Answer (score 0):

You can declare multiple variables within an expression, Measure/Calculated Column/Calculated Table. Just keep in mind they will only be evaluated if refered to, lazy evaluation, and once assigned within it's scope they can't be overwritten.

Example:

```
My Calculation = 
    var a = 1
    var b = 2
RETURN
    a+b
```

Your problem might be with the incorrect use of the IF.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/dax/if-function-dax

Example:

```
My Calculation = 
    var a = "Customer 1001"
RETURN
    IF(a = "Customer 1001", "USA" , "Other")
```